# How do you turn on flags for a capturing subgroup using re2 regular expressions with BigQuery

Tags: regex, google-bigquery, re2

This question is specific to the re2 regular expression library by Google. There are other solution for this problem in other engines, but they dont apply to re2

I wish to use flags such as `i` (case insensitive) and `s` (dot matches new line) in BigQuery using REGEXP_REPLACE, with the condition that its use does not make the group a non-capturing group as mandated by re2.

For the inputs,
`My name is X`, `my Name is Y`, `MY NAME is Z`, i wish to replace X,Y,Z with some constant C, such that the output is for ex. `My name is C`

I know that you can use these flags in the following way i.e `(?is:My name is )(\w+).` , however the first group becomes a non-capturing group, that doesnt allow me to refer to it via a number such as `\1` like this (since \1 refers to X, instead of `my name is`)

`REGEXP_REPLACE(str, r'(?is:My name is )(\w+). ', r'\1 C')`

How can i use flags with capturing groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a nested capturing group within the non-capturing group like this

`(?is:(My name is ))(\w+)`

`REGEXP_REPLACE(str, r'(?is:(My name is ))(\w+). ', r'\1 C')`